# Saving longer list of previous debugging sessions in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, properties-file, jpda

When debugging remote applications, Netbeans remembers the last three, and shows the most recent in  the Attach dialog.

[image: Attach debugger Menu]

[image: Attach debugger Dialog]

My question is whether anyone has looked into a plugin or another solution, where you can attach to multiple servers at once (we have a bunch of servers behind a load-balancer, with no session persistence, so I can't predefine which server the request will hit), or a way to save more than three previous servers?

EDIT:
I have discovered that the file containing the settings for the last "attaches" is 
`%APPDATA%\NetBeans\8.0.2\config\Services\org-netbeans-modules-debugger-Settings.properties`

Based on the [Netbeans FAQ article regarding userdir](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir)

original settings:

```
debugger.last_attaches.used_slots:# array
debugger.last_attaches.used_slots.0:# java.lang.Integer
debugger.last_attaches.used_slots.0.primitiveWrapper:1
debugger.last_attaches.used_slots.1:# java.lang.Integer
debugger.last_attaches.used_slots.1.primitiveWrapper:3
debugger.last_attaches.used_slots.2:# java.lang.Integer
debugger.last_attaches.used_slots.2.primitiveWrapper:2
debugger.last_attaches.used_slots.array_type:java.lang.Integer
debugger.last_attaches.used_slots.length:3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix, altering a lot of settings in the aforementioned properties file:
note that the values in the first section have to be present for the incremented number of slots, defined below will show

**Last connections:**

```
debugger.last_attach_type:"Java Debugger (JPDA)"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_0.attach_type:"Java Debugger (JPDA)"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_0.display_name:"Attach to someserver0484.somedomain.local:8888"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_0.values.attaching_connector:"com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_0.values.connection_settings:# java.util.HashMap
debugger.last_attaches.slot_0.values.connection_settings.0-key:"com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_0.values.connection_settings.0-value:# java.util.HashMap
debugger.last_attaches.slot_0.values.connection_settings.0-value.0-key:"port"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_0.values.connection_settings.0-value.0-value:"8888"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_0.values.connection_settings.0-value.1-key:"hostname"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_0.values.connection_settings.0-value.1-value:"someservercs0484.somedomain.local"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_0.values.connection_settings.0-value.2-key:"timeout"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_0.values.connection_settings.0-value.2-value:"50000"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_0.values.connection_settings.0-value.length:3
debugger.last_attaches.slot_0.values.connection_settings.length:1
debugger.last_attaches.slot_1.attach_type:"Java Debugger (JPDA)"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_1.display_name:"Attach to someserver0137.somedomain.local:8888"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_1.values.attaching_connector:"com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_1.values.connection_settings:# java.util.HashMap
debugger.last_attaches.slot_1.values.connection_settings.0-key:"com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_1.values.connection_settings.0-value:# java.util.HashMap
debugger.last_attaches.slot_1.values.connection_settings.0-value.0-key:"port"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_1.values.connection_settings.0-value.0-value:"8888"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_1.values.connection_settings.0-value.1-key:"hostname"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_1.values.connection_settings.0-value.1-value:"someserver0137.somedomain.local"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_1.values.connection_settings.0-value.2-key:"timeout"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_1.values.connection_settings.0-value.2-value:"50000"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_1.values.connection_settings.0-value.length:3
debugger.last_attaches.slot_1.values.connection_settings.length:1
debugger.last_attaches.slot_10.attach_type:"Java Debugger (JPDA)"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_10.display_name:"Attach to someserver0136.somedomain.local:8888"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_10.values.attaching_connector:"com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_10.values.connection_settings:# java.util.HashMap
debugger.last_attaches.slot_10.values.connection_settings.0-key:"com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_10.values.connection_settings.0-value:# java.util.HashMap
debugger.last_attaches.slot_10.values.connection_settings.0-value.0-key:"port"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_10.values.connection_settings.0-value.0-value:"8888"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_10.values.connection_settings.0-value.1-key:"hostname"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_10.values.connection_settings.0-value.1-value:"someserver0136.somedomain.local"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_10.values.connection_settings.0-value.2-key:"timeout"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_10.values.connection_settings.0-value.2-value:"50000"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_10.values.connection_settings.0-value.length:3
debugger.last_attaches.slot_10.values.connection_settings.length:1
debugger.last_attaches.slot_2.attach_type:"Java Debugger (JPDA)"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_2.display_name:"Attach to someserver0135.somedomain.local:8888"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_2.values.attaching_connector:"com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_2.values.connection_settings:# java.util.HashMap
debugger.last_attaches.slot_2.values.connection_settings.0-key:"com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_2.values.connection_settings.0-value:# java.util.HashMap
debugger.last_attaches.slot_2.values.connection_settings.0-value.0-key:"port"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_2.values.connection_settings.0-value.0-value:"8888"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_2.values.connection_settings.0-value.1-key:"hostname"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_2.values.connection_settings.0-value.1-value:"someserver0135.somedomain.local"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_2.values.connection_settings.0-value.2-key:"timeout"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_2.values.connection_settings.0-value.2-value:"50000"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_2.values.connection_settings.0-value.length:3
debugger.last_attaches.slot_2.values.connection_settings.length:1
debugger.last_attaches.slot_3.attach_type:"Java Debugger (JPDA)"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_3.display_name:"Attach to someserver0136.somedomain.local:8888"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_3.values.attaching_connector:"com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_3.values.connection_settings:# java.util.HashMap
debugger.last_attaches.slot_3.values.connection_settings.0-key:"com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_3.values.connection_settings.0-value:# java.util.HashMap
debugger.last_attaches.slot_3.values.connection_settings.0-value.0-key:"port"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_3.values.connection_settings.0-value.0-value:"8888"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_3.values.connection_settings.0-value.1-key:"hostname"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_3.values.connection_settings.0-value.1-value:"someserver0136.somedomain.local"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_3.values.connection_settings.0-value.2-key:"timeout"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_3.values.connection_settings.0-value.2-value:"50000"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_3.values.connection_settings.0-value.length:3
debugger.last_attaches.slot_3.values.connection_settings.length:1
debugger.last_attaches.slot_4.attach_type:"Java Debugger (JPDA)"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_4.display_name:"Attach to someserver0137.somedomain.local:8888"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_4.values.attaching_connector:"com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_4.values.connection_settings:# java.util.HashMap
debugger.last_attaches.slot_4.values.connection_settings.0-key:"com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_4.values.connection_settings.0-value:# java.util.HashMap
debugger.last_attaches.slot_4.values.connection_settings.0-value.0-key:"port"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_4.values.connection_settings.0-value.0-value:"8888"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_4.values.connection_settings.0-value.1-key:"hostname"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_4.values.connection_settings.0-value.1-value:"someserver0137.somedomain.local"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_4.values.connection_settings.0-value.2-key:"timeout"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_4.values.connection_settings.0-value.2-value:"50000"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_4.values.connection_settings.0-value.length:3
debugger.last_attaches.slot_4.values.connection_settings.length:1
debugger.last_attaches.slot_5.attach_type:"Java Debugger (JPDA)"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_5.display_name:"Attach to someserver0136.somedomain.local:8888"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_5.values.attaching_connector:"com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_5.values.connection_settings:# java.util.HashMap
debugger.last_attaches.slot_5.values.connection_settings.0-key:"com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_5.values.connection_settings.0-value:# java.util.HashMap
debugger.last_attaches.slot_5.values.connection_settings.0-value.0-key:"port"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_5.values.connection_settings.0-value.0-value:"8888"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_5.values.connection_settings.0-value.1-key:"hostname"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_5.values.connection_settings.0-value.1-value:"someserver0136.somedomain.local"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_5.values.connection_settings.0-value.2-key:"timeout"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_5.values.connection_settings.0-value.2-value:"50000"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_5.values.connection_settings.0-value.length:3
debugger.last_attaches.slot_5.values.connection_settings.length:1
debugger.last_attaches.slot_6.attach_type:"Java Debugger (JPDA)"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_6.display_name:"Attach to someserver0136.somedomain.local:8888"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_6.values.attaching_connector:"com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_6.values.connection_settings:# java.util.HashMap
debugger.last_attaches.slot_6.values.connection_settings.0-key:"com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_6.values.connection_settings.0-value:# java.util.HashMap
debugger.last_attaches.slot_6.values.connection_settings.0-value.0-key:"port"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_6.values.connection_settings.0-value.0-value:"8888"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_6.values.connection_settings.0-value.1-key:"hostname"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_6.values.connection_settings.0-value.1-value:"someserver0136.somedomain.local"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_6.values.connection_settings.0-value.2-key:"timeout"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_6.values.connection_settings.0-value.2-value:"50000"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_6.values.connection_settings.0-value.length:3
debugger.last_attaches.slot_6.values.connection_settings.length:1
debugger.last_attaches.slot_7.attach_type:"Java Debugger (JPDA)"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_7.display_name:"Attach to someserver0136.somedomain.local:8888"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_7.values.attaching_connector:"com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_7.values.connection_settings:# java.util.HashMap
debugger.last_attaches.slot_7.values.connection_settings.0-key:"com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_7.values.connection_settings.0-value:# java.util.HashMap
debugger.last_attaches.slot_7.values.connection_settings.0-value.0-key:"port"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_7.values.connection_settings.0-value.0-value:"8888"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_7.values.connection_settings.0-value.1-key:"hostname"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_7.values.connection_settings.0-value.1-value:"someserver0136.somedomain.local"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_7.values.connection_settings.0-value.2-key:"timeout"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_7.values.connection_settings.0-value.2-value:"50000"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_7.values.connection_settings.0-value.length:3
debugger.last_attaches.slot_7.values.connection_settings.length:1
debugger.last_attaches.slot_8.attach_type:"Java Debugger (JPDA)"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_8.display_name:"Attach to someserver0136.somedomain.local:8888"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_8.values.attaching_connector:"com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_8.values.connection_settings:# java.util.HashMap
debugger.last_attaches.slot_8.values.connection_settings.0-key:"com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_8.values.connection_settings.0-value:# java.util.HashMap
debugger.last_attaches.slot_8.values.connection_settings.0-value.0-key:"port"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_8.values.connection_settings.0-value.0-value:"8888"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_8.values.connection_settings.0-value.1-key:"hostname"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_8.values.connection_settings.0-value.1-value:"someserver0136.somedomain.local"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_8.values.connection_settings.0-value.2-key:"timeout"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_8.values.connection_settings.0-value.2-value:"50000"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_8.values.connection_settings.0-value.length:3
debugger.last_attaches.slot_8.values.connection_settings.length:1
debugger.last_attaches.slot_9.attach_type:"Java Debugger (JPDA)"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_9.display_name:"Attach to someserver0136.somedomain.local:8888"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_9.values.attaching_connector:"com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_9.values.connection_settings:# java.util.HashMap
debugger.last_attaches.slot_9.values.connection_settings.0-key:"com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_9.values.connection_settings.0-value:# java.util.HashMap
debugger.last_attaches.slot_9.values.connection_settings.0-value.0-key:"port"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_9.values.connection_settings.0-value.0-value:"8888"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_9.values.connection_settings.0-value.1-key:"hostname"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_9.values.connection_settings.0-value.1-value:"someserver0136.somedomain.local"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_9.values.connection_settings.0-value.2-key:"timeout"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_9.values.connection_settings.0-value.2-value:"50000"
debugger.last_attaches.slot_9.values.connection_settings.0-value.length:3
debugger.last_attaches.slot_9.values.connection_settings.length:1
```

**Slots:**

```
debugger.last_attaches.used_slots:# array
debugger.last_attaches.used_slots.0:# java.lang.Integer
debugger.last_attaches.used_slots.0.primitiveWrapper:1
debugger.last_attaches.used_slots.1:# java.lang.Integer
debugger.last_attaches.used_slots.1.primitiveWrapper:2
debugger.last_attaches.used_slots.2:# java.lang.Integer
debugger.last_attaches.used_slots.2.primitiveWrapper:3
debugger.last_attaches.used_slots.3:# java.lang.Integer
debugger.last_attaches.used_slots.3.primitiveWrapper:4
debugger.last_attaches.used_slots.4:# java.lang.Integer
debugger.last_attaches.used_slots.4.primitiveWrapper:5
debugger.last_attaches.used_slots.5:# java.lang.Integer
debugger.last_attaches.used_slots.5.primitiveWrapper:6
debugger.last_attaches.used_slots.6:# java.lang.Integer
debugger.last_attaches.used_slots.6.primitiveWrapper:7
debugger.last_attaches.used_slots.7:# java.lang.Integer
debugger.last_attaches.used_slots.7.primitiveWrapper:8
debugger.last_attaches.used_slots.8:# java.lang.Integer
debugger.last_attaches.used_slots.8.primitiveWrapper:9
debugger.last_attaches.used_slots.9:# java.lang.Integer
debugger.last_attaches.used_slots.9.primitiveWrapper:10
debugger.last_attaches.used_slots.array_type:java.lang.Integer
debugger.last_attaches.used_slots.length:10
debugger.last_attaching_connector:"com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach"
```

**My new Attach Debugger Menu**
So now I have plenty more saved slots:
[image: My new Attach Debugger Menu]

EDIT:

It turns out that you CAN save debugging sessions like this, but if you create a new, the list is cleared. working on that.